# Fusion Chart - Can we apply effect or animation before loading chart

Tags: fusioncharts

I am using `Fusion Chart 3.1.1` and want to give **some animation effect before chart loading**. By default some loading is coming before chart loading by Fusion Chart.

Can we customise that and can use our loading image(like animation image ) or Fusion chart has provided something like this where we can do modification and change.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the loading text "Loading Chart. Please Wait.", which is visible by default when the chart is getting loaded, to show some other text of your choice. This can be done using configure() function with "LoadingText" or "PBarLoadingText" chart message. For more information,refer : http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/index.html?advanced/ChartMessages.html

However, it is not possible to show an animating image till the chart is rendered.

Comment: Can we do this by trick. Because on mobile it looks very bad simple showing some text , we can show some loading image while data loading.